# Unable to connect to my API using HTTP Client in Unity

Tags: c#, android, node.js, http, unity-game-engine

I am using this [HTTP Client](https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient) to my Unity project.

I have build an API which works fine at my MEAN stack (Angular, Node.js, ...)

**When I build my Unity project to my Android device**, and I try to make a call to my unity project I am getting the error

> "Cannot connect to destination host"

This is how I do the API call to Unity & C#:

```
public void Get()
{
    string basePath="http://___myIP___:80/api"

    RestClient.GetArray<User>(basePath + "/users").Then(res => {
        Debug.Log("Users", JsonHelper.ArrayToJsonString<User>(res, true));
    }).Catch(err => this.LogMessage("Error", err.Message));
}
```

> It works fine If I hit play to unity editor to my machine. It does not work when I build to the Android device

Comment: Hey have you tried Refit? It looks like a better implementation of a rest client and it's based on the normal HttpClientFactory. Maybe it's working better then the Unity Lib you are using right now. As it's autoimplementing your restclient based on the normal HTTPClient, Interfaces and annotations. Maybe this is a cleaner and more stable approach?

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit

Comment: The android device needs to either be on the same LAN as the computer hosting the API or the API needs to be accessible outside of your LAN (aka, port forwarded at your router). The api can't be bound to localhost (127.0.0.1) either, but you can use 0.0.0.0 instead. If you're on Windows, you'll also need to ensure port 80 isn't blocked by its firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer, but in case someone reaches to this desperate situation and has the same problem with me, the problem was that in my laboratory to my machine the IP address was changed from 137... into 192..., an address that does not accept API calls from external devices.

Anybody who cross this issue can have this in mind too.